# How to get/export all of the data from a Cassandra DB

Tags: cassandra, export

In a project that I am working on, we are planning migrate from Cassandra DB to other technology,

The problem is how to get all of the data out of cassandra? (We are talking about 4M-8M records)

Answer (score 0):

I should try exporting data to CSV file and then import it to another db.
To export data to CSV you can start with cpoy to command ..if that does not work then a simple Java program described in [this](https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/moshimon.wordpress.com/2015/01/19/export-data-from-cassandra-to-csv/amp/) can help you for bigger set of data.

But more importantly you should understand the data model of other technology before importing data into it..you may need to change your data model..

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at other tools like https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader. I have imported/exported data in terms of hundreds of million using this application.